# multiple mouse events are fired on mouse click

Tags: javascript, dojo, mouseevent, dojox.gfx

I created a dojo graphic group and hooked couple of mouse events to it, but the mouseclick event fire all other mouse events, I haven't moved the mouse while clicking.

A **mouse click** fired both '**mouseout**', '**mouseenter**' and finally '**mousedown**'.

Anyone has any ideas?

```
var group = surface.createGroup();
group.on("mousedown", function(e) { handle mouse click here });
group.on("mouseout", function(e) { handle mouse out here });
group.on("mouseenter", function(e) { handle mouse enter here });
```

UPDATE: I was recreating the graphic on the mouse enter and that caused all sorts of problems.

Comment: There should be a mouse *up* too, given that by definition a "click" is a mouse down event followed by a mouse up on the same element. (Regarding the mouse enter, doesn't this occur because you had to move the mouse over the element in question before you could click it? Which would give you a mouse out event from whatever other element the mouse was originally over...)

Comment: I didn't move the at all (at least I tried not to move while clicking, still fires all these events). Do you know where I can find the detailed description of javascript mouse event handling. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dojo/mouse` (http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/mouse) :

```
var group = surface.createGroup();
group.on("mousedown", function(e) { handle mouse click here });
group.on(mouse.leave, function(e) { handle mouse out here });
group.on(mouse.enter, function(e) { handle mouse enter here });
```

I guess `click` should be better than `mousedown` as you wrote "handle mouse click here"